# terraform - how to tag azure notification hub

Tags: azure, terraform

I've tried to create an Azure notification hub namespace and Azure notification hub.

I see the doc by the official terraform site, and the tag argument is available. (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/notification_hub.html#tags)

But is not possible, as you can see:

```
resource "azurerm_notification_hub_namespace" "nothub_ns" {
  name                = "${var.nh_namespace_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.rgname}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  namespace_type      = "NotificationHub"

  sku_name = "${var.sku_type}"

  tags = {
    acronimo = "${var.acronimo}"
  }

}
```

But i retrieve this error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on TemplateNotificationHub.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_notification_hub_namespace" "nothub_ns":
  31:   tags = {

An argument named "tags" is not expected here.
```

Terraform version
Terraform v0.12.24

Azure provider version: 2.06.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is **Azure Provider Version issue**.

If you add the [latest version](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2140-june-11-2020) of Azure Provider i.e. **2.14.0**, You won't face this error: "An argument named "tags" is not expected here". Check out the [changelog](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for version information and release notes.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.14.0"
  features {}
}
```